# What does the (∂X) symbol means in Matrix Cookbook?

Tags: matrix-calculus

Check page 8 and equation 34 of [Matrix Cookbook](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/3274/pdf/imm3274.pdf).

In this simple case we take the derivative of a matrix that is multiplied by a constant and we have: $\partial (aX) = a*(\partial X)$

Probably missing something crucial because I would expect ∂aX/∂X = a

So what does (∂X) represents exactly?

Comment: You did not faithfully reproduce equation (34). And that difference is crucial to your question. The LHS is a differential, not a derivative.

Comment: LHS ?? Could you elaborate @MarkL.Stone? Thank you

Comment: Left hand side of the equation.

Comment: Thanks @MatthewDrury. Now makes sense?

Comment: Question is edited/fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation:$$\partial (aX) = a*(\partial X)$$ is referred to ''differentials'' and 
means exactly that:
$$
\frac{\partial (aX)}{\partial X} = a
$$

Comment: Now I got the twist. Thank you. I originally thought that the denominator (differentiating with..) was omitted only for brevity. Thank you for clarifying